# Rails - Group by JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, serialization, grouping

I have a model like this:

```
class Analytic < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :properties, JSON
end
```

which returns records with properties like this:

```
properties: {searchQuery: "hello world"}
```

In my controller after collecting all of the records I can group them like so:

```
group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month.strftime('%m%Y')  }
```

How can I group all the properties by the `searchQuery` index in the properties JSON object?

Comment: Have you tried `group_by { |t| t.properties['searchQuery']  }` ?

Comment: @Dharam will try that and will let you know, thanks :)

Comment: @Dharam that worked! Can you leave an answer with that solution and I'll select it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

group_by { |t| t.properties['searchQuery'] }